# Building a console application using a DI service container

Tags: php, console, dependency-injection, symfony2

I am working on a project that will allow developers to create a console application using a dependency injection service container. Both the console and container are Symfony components with some glue code to make it all work together.

The project can be found [here](https://github.com/kherge/php-shell) and the script in question is [here](https://github.com/kherge/php-shell/blob/master/src/lib/KHerGe/Shell/Application.php).

I'm hoping that some people with more experience using either component could chime in on anything I am doing wrong, or mention things you would like to see supported in case it could be useful to you.

```
<?php

namespace KHerGe\Shell;

use KHerGe\Shell\DependencyInjection\CommandCompilerPass;
use KHerGe\Shell\DependencyInjection\EventDispatcherCompilerPass;
use KHerGe\Shell\DependencyInjection\HelperCompilerPass;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\DelegatingLoader;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderResolver;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\IniFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\PhpFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\YamlFileLoader;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

/**
 * Manages the assembly of a console application using a service container.
 *
 * @author Kevin Herrera <kevin@herrera.io>
 */
class Application
{
    /**
     * The service container.
     *
     * @var ContainerBuilder
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * The compiled state of the service container.
     *
     * @var boolean
     */
    private $compiled = false;

    /**
     * The list of default helpers.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    private static $helpers = array(
        'shell.console.helper.descriptor' => 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DescriptorHelper',
        'shell.console.helper.dialog' => 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\DialogHelper',
        'shell.console.helper.formatter' => 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\FormatterHelper',
        'shell.console.helper.progress' => 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\ProgressHelper',
        'shell.console.helper.table' => 'Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\TableHelper',
    );

    /**
     * Sets the service container.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container The service container.
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerBuilder $container = null)
    {
        if (null === $container) {
            $container = new ContainerBuilder();
        }

        $this->buildContainer($container);

        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Shell application.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container The service container.
     *
     * @return Application The new Shell application.
     */
    public static function create(ContainerBuilder $container = null)
    {
        return new static($container);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the service container.
     *
     * @return ContainerBuilder The service container.
     */
    public function getContainer()
    {
        return $this->container;
    }

    /**
     * Loads a service container configuration file.
     *
     * @param string $file The path to the configuration file.
     *
     * @return Application The same Shell application.
     */
    public function load($file)
    {
        $locator = new FileLocator(dirname($file));
        $loaders = array(
            new IniFileLoader($this->container, $locator),
            new PhpFileLoader($this->container, $locator),
        );

        if (class_exists('DOMDocument')) {
            $loaders[] = new XmlFileLoader($this->container, $locator);
        }

        if (class_exists('Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml')) {
            $loaders[] = new YamlFileLoader($this->container, $locator);
        }

        $loader = new DelegatingLoader(new LoaderResolver($loaders));
        $loader->load(basename($file));

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Runs the Shell console application.
     *
     * @return integer The command exit status.
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (false === $this->compiled) {
            $this->compiled = true;

            $this->container->compile();
        }

        return $this->container->get('shell.console')->run(
            $this->container->get('shell.console.input'),
            $this->container->get('shell.console.output')
        );
    }

    /**
     * Builds the container with default services.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container The service container.
     */
    private function buildContainer(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->has('shell.container')) {
            $container->set('shell.container', $container);
        }

        $container->addCompilerPass(new CommandCompilerPass());
        $container->addCompilerPass(new EventDispatcherCompilerPass());
        $container->addCompilerPass(new HelperCompilerPass());

        $this->setConsole($container);
        $this->setEventDispatcher($container);
        $this->setHelperSet($container);
        $this->setInput($container);
        $this->setOutput($container);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a console definition, if one has not already been set.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container The container builder.
     */
    private function setConsole(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('shell.console')) {
            $definition = new Definition('Symfony\Component\Console\Application');
            $definition->addArgument('%app.name%');
            $definition->addArgument('%app.version%');

            $container->setDefinition('shell.console', $definition);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an event dispatcher definition, if one has not already been set.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container The container builder.
     */
    private function setEventDispatcher(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('shell.console.event_dispatcher')) {
            $container->setDefinition(
                'shell.console.event_dispatcher',
                new Definition('Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher')
            );

            $container->getDefinition('shell.console')->addMethodCall(
                'setDispatcher',
                array(new Reference('shell.console.event_dispatcher'))
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a helper set, if one has not already been set.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container The container builder.
     */
    private function setHelperSet(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('shell.console.helper_set')) {
            $container->setDefinition(
                'shell.console.helper_set',
                new Definition('Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet')
            );
        }

        foreach (self::$helpers as $id => $class) {
            if (class_exists($class)) {
                if (!$container->hasDefinition($id)) {
                    $definition = new Definition($class);
                    $definition->addTag('shell.console.helper');
                    $container->setDefinition($id, $definition);
                }
            }
        }

        $container->getDefinition('shell.console')->addMethodCall(
            'setHelperSet',
            array(new Reference('shell.console.helper_set'))
        );
    }

    /**
     * Creates a console input definition, if one has not already been set.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container The container builder.
     */
    private function setInput(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('shell.console.input')) {
            $container->setDefinition(
                'shell.console.input',
                new Definition('Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput')
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a console output definition, if one has not already been set.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container The container builder.
     */
    private function setOutput(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('shell.console.output')) {
            $container->setDefinition(
                'shell.console.output',
                new Definition('Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput')
            );
        }
    }
}
```